# Spring Redis Error Handle

Tags: error-handling, redis, spring-data, jedis

I am using Spring + Redis as my cache component in the new project. The spring config xml file is:

```
<!-- Jedis Connection --> 
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    p:host-name="${redis.ip}" p:port="${redis.port}" p:use-pool="${redis.use-pool}" />

<!-- Redis Template -->
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="keySerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />
    </property>
    <property name="valueSerializer">  
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer" />
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager" c:template-ref="redisTemplate"/>

<cache:annotation-driven mode="proxy" proxy-target-class="true" cache-manager="cacheManager" />
```

The usage is

```
    @Cacheable(value = "cacheManager", key="#userId")
public User getUser(String userId) {
    System.out.println("execute==");
    return userAdminMapper.getUser(userId);
}
```

My test case is:

```
@Test
public void testCacheUser2() {
    String id = "test";
    User user = userService.getUser(id);
    System.out.println(user);
    user.setUserCreateDate(new Date());
    userService.updateUser(user);
    User user2 = userService.getUser(id);
    System.out.println(user2);
    User user3 = userService.getUser(id);
    System.out.println(user3);
}
```

If the Redis server is running, the code is running correctly. But my question is if I shutdown the Redis server, it will throw the exception:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:177)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:87)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInAnyCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:287)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.collectPutRequests(CacheAspectSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:199)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:178)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at sg.infolab.common.admin.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c7f982a7.getUser(<generated>)
    at sg.infolab.admin.test.RedisServiceTest.testCacheUser2(RedisServiceTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:150)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:71)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1783)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:137)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:144)
    ... 53 more
```

I want to ask if the client couldn't connect Redis Server, why will it throw exception? Can we config the scenario like this -- if the cache layer(Redis Server) cannot connect(maybe it is crashed or network is not up), it should directly connect to database and fetch data.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the very same problem. I'm developing some data services against a database, using Redis as the cache store by way of Spring Caching annotations. If the Redis server becomes unavailable, I want the services to continue to operate as if uncached, rather than throwing exceptions.

At first I tried a custom CacheErrorHandler, a mechanism provided by Spring. It didn't quite work, because it only handles RuntimeExceptions, and still lets things like java.net.ConnectException blow things up.

In the end what I did is extend RedisTemplate, overriding a few execute() methods so that they log warnings instead of propagating exceptions. It seems like a bit of a hack, and I might have overridden too few execute() methods or too many, but it works like a charm in all my test cases.

There's an important operational aspect to this approach, though. If the Redis server becomes unavailable you must flush it (clean out the entries) before making it available again. Otherwise there's a chance that you might start retrieving cache entries that have incorrect data because of updates that occurred in the meantime.

Below is the source. Feel free to use it. I hope it helps.

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisCallback;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.SessionCallback;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.RedisScript;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializer;


/**
 * An extension of RedisTemplate that logs exceptions instead of letting them propagate.
 * If the Redis server is unavailable, cache operations are always a "miss" and data is fetched from the database.
 */
public class LoggingRedisTemplate<K, V> extends RedisTemplate<K, V> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingRedisTemplate.class);


    @Override
    public <T> T execute(final RedisCallback<T> action, final boolean exposeConnection, final boolean pipeline) {
        try {
            return super.execute(action, exposeConnection, pipeline);
        }
        catch(final Throwable t) {
            logger.warn("Error executing cache operation: {}", t.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public <T> T execute(final RedisScript<T> script, final List<K> keys, final Object... args) {
        try {
            return super.execute(script, keys, args);
        }
        catch(final Throwable t) {
            logger.warn("Error executing cache operation: {}", t.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public <T> T execute(final RedisScript<T> script, final RedisSerializer<?> argsSerializer, final RedisSerializer<T> resultSerializer, final List<K> keys, final Object... args) {
        try {
            return super.execute(script, argsSerializer, resultSerializer, keys, args);
        }
        catch(final Throwable t) {
            logger.warn("Error executing cache operation: {}", t.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public <T> T execute(final SessionCallback<T> session) {
        try {
            return super.execute(session);
        }
        catch(final Throwable t) {
            logger.warn("Error executing cache operation: {}", t.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a nice feature to have rolled into spring-data. Has anyone opened up a ticket or PR to discuss this with the team?

Comment: Thanks for that, @KevinCrowell. I might put it out there as a project of its own because, in retrospect, it might need enhancement. The above code presumes that Redis was completely down, and unpersisted, and therefore would be empty when it becomes available. In the event that Redis was only temporarily unreachable, or if Redis went down but the caches were persisted, updates to the database would still have gone through and the cache entries could be stale. Perhaps it should "remember" cache keys received while Redis was unavailable, and evict them when Redis becomes available.

Comment: Unfortunately this is really bad antipattern many experienced developers still follow. In very typical scenario application will hang because you catch InterruptedException here, in some other scenario it will hang because of caught OutOfMemoryError and even logger hangs and DevOps will have no idea "why", and so on.

Answer (score 7):

I have added the answer for Spring boot v2 using LettuceConnectionFactory

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport implements CachingConfigurer {

    @Value("${redis.hostname:localhost}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${redis.port:6379}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Value("${redis.timeout.secs:1}")
    private int redisTimeoutInSecs;

    @Value("${redis.socket.timeout.secs:1}")
    private int redisSocketTimeoutInSecs;

    @Value("${redis.ttl.hours:1}")
    private int redisDataTTL;

    // @Autowired
    // private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        // LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
        // .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(redisConnectionTimeoutInSecs)).shutdownTimeout(Duration.ZERO).build();
        //
        // return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort), clientConfig);

        final SocketOptions socketOptions = SocketOptions.builder().connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(redisSocketTimeoutInSecs)).build();

        final ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder().socketOptions(socketOptions).build();

        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(redisTimeoutInSecs)).clientOptions(clientOptions).build();
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);

        final LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig, clientConfig);
        lettuceConnectionFactory.setValidateConnection(true);
        return lettuceConnectionFactory;

    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {

        /**
         * If we want to use JSON Serialized with own object mapper then use the below config snippet
         */
        // RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration =
        // RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().disableCachingNullValues()
        // .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(redisDataTTL)).serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair
        // .fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)));

        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().disableCachingNullValues()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(redisDataTTL))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.java()));

        redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();

        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();

        redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
        return redisCacheManager;
    }


    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new RedisCacheErrorHandler();
    }
```

RedisCacheErrorHandler.java is given below

```
public class RedisCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisCacheErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        handleTimeOutException(exception);
        log.info("Unable to get from cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        handleTimeOutException(exception);
        log.info("Unable to put into cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        handleTimeOutException(exception);
        log.info("Unable to evict from cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
        handleTimeOutException(exception);
        log.info("Unable to clean cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    /**
     * We handle redis connection timeout exception , if the exception is handled then it is treated as a cache miss and
     * gets the data from actual storage
     * 
     * @param exception
     */
    private void handleTimeOutException(RuntimeException exception) {

        if (exception instanceof RedisCommandTimeoutException)
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was facing the issue with redis connection timeout which was taking approximately 10-20 seconds.It was helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error. And I managed to solve it by adding two things:

- timeout for connectionFactory
- error handler

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "redis.enabled", havingValue = "true")
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport implements CachingConfigurer {

    @Value("${redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${redis.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${redis.expiration.timeout}")
    private Integer expirationTimeout;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        redisConnectionFactory.setTimeout(10);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Set<String>> redisTemplate(@Autowired RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Set<String>> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(@Autowired RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(expirationTimeout);
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new RedisCacheErrorHandler();
    }

    @Slf4j
    public static class RedisCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {

        @Override
        public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
            log.info("Unable to get from cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
            log.info("Unable to put into cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
            log.info("Unable to evict from cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
            log.info("Unable to clean cache " + cache.getName() + " : " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LettuceConnectionFactory is not necessary. Just using a custom CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport. And override the errorHandler() method.

You just need to implement a custom CacheErrorHandler, like @Tan mally do in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CacheErrorHandler` as suggested in other answers. But you should make sure to make
`RedisCacheManager transactionAware` to `false` in your Redis Cache Config(to make sure the transaction is committed early when executing the caching part and the error is caught by `CacheErrorHandler` and don't wait until the end of the execution which skips `CacheErrorHandler` part). The function to set `transactionAware` to `false` looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
        JdkSerializationRedisSerializer redisSerializer = new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(getClass().getClassLoader());

        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(redisDataTTL))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(redisSerializer));

        redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();

        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration)
                .build();

        redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(false);
        return redisCacheManager;
    }
```