# Spring boot: If Jedis connection pool is not available, tell server to fetch data from database instead of throwing errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Say if the connection to redis is unavailable, assume cache does not exist and fetch it directly from database, instead of failing the entire app instead

```
@Cachable
public String cachingMethod(String cache) {
    return "cache";
}
```

I was following this answer on SO:
[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021991/spring-redis-error-handle)

But my spring boot still throws Exception on bootup and it does not fetch data from database:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
...
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
...
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

my configuration code is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisConfig {  
    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Bean
    public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig() {
        JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(128);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(128);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMinIdle(16);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(
            Duration.ofSeconds(60).toMillis());

        jedisPoolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(
            Duration.ofSeconds(30).toMillis());
        jedisPoolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
        jedisPoolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);

        return jedisPoolConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new 
        JedisConnectionFactory(jedisPoolConfig());
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
        jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();

        if (null == jedisConnectionFactory()) {
            logger.error("Redis template service is not available");
            return null;
        };

        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.afterPropertiesSet();

        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager() {
        Map<String, Long> expires = new HashMap<>();
        expires.put("user:profile", 300L);


        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new 
        RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
        redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        redisCacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(300);
        redisCacheManager.setExpires(expires);

        return redisCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new KeyGenerator() {
            @Override
            public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... objects) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(o.getClass().getName());
                sb.append(method.getName());
                for (Object obj : objects) {
                    sb.append(obj.toString());
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: A circuit breaker (like Hystrix) would be the appropriate integration (https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/)